# jQuery autocomplete issue using a JSP file as the source

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement auto complete on my search field. Everything works fine when the source I use is a simple JavaScript array (see var data = [ ... ]) like this:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Basic Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-    ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.catcomplete.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
```

```
$(function() {

    var data = [
                { label: "Eric Cartman", category: "Users" },
                { label: "John Lennon", category: "Users" }, 
                { label: "Elvis Presley", category: "Users" },
                { label: "Steven Gerrard", category: "Users" },
                { label: "Java", category: "Programming" },
                { label: "C#", category: "Programming" },
                { label: "C++", category: "Programming" }, 
                { label: "Python", category: "Programming" },
                { label: "Ruby on Rails", category: "Programming" }
            ];
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        source: data
    });
});
</script>

<p />

<div class="container well">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form action="search" method="get">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" name="query" id="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to implement the exact same thing with a JSP file as a source like this:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.catcomplete.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
    }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 3,
        source: 'getsearchjson.jsp'
    });
});
</script>

<p />

<div class="container well">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form action="search" method="get">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" name="query" id="search" placeholder="Search.."/>
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

getsearchjson.jsp:

```
<% 
    response.setContentType("application/json");
%>
[
    { label: "Eric Cartman", category: "Users" },
    { label: "John Lennon", category: "Users" }, 
    { label: "Elvis Presley", category: "Users" },
    { label: "Steven Gerrard", category: "Users" },
    { label: "Java", category: "Programming" },
    { label: "C#", category: "Programming" },
    { label: "C++", category: "Programming" }, 
    { label: "Python", category: "Programming" },
    { label: "Ruby on Rails", category: "Programming" }
];
```

It stops working, that is, the auto complete functionality is not present on my search field anymore.

To clarify: The only difference between the first implementation and the second is the source from which the data is pulled. In the first implementation it's a JavaScript array, in the second implementation it's a JSP file.

Thanks for any response. For your information, my JavaScript knowledge is extremely limited as it's not part of the curriculum at my university. However, I would like to use it to make the web application look more professional.

Comment: Check that the URL is correct. Use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see if a request is being sent to your JSP, and what the response is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. By using the Chrome developer tools I can see that a request is being sent and that the response is in fact the JSON data from the getsearchjson.jsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your JSP doesn't contain valid JSON data. Keys should be surrounded by double quotes to make it valid JSON:

```
[
    { "label": "Eric Cartman", "category": "Users" },
    { "label": "John Lennon", "category": "Users" }, 
    ...
```

Use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to check the validity of your JSON.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the problem. After I put quotes around the keys and removed the semicolon at the end of getsearchjson.jsp I've gotten closer to a solution. I am now getting suggestions when I type in the search field as expected, however, I am getting _everything_ in the getsearchjson.jsp regardless of what I type in. Any ideas how to proceed? I suspect the problem is in the first <script> block. Note that this was working perfectly before, when the data was stored in a JavaScript array.

Comment: Look at the [API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) of autocomplete. It says: *When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter term gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results.*